# Is there a shortcut to change bulk BMP images to JPG images in a site?

Tags: images, database

Images in WordPress posts, as I understand, are uploaded manually. They are uploaded by default to `uploads` folder. A client of mine reported that, in one of his site, he uploaded all the images in BMP format. Now he realized the consequences of his mistake. He wants to make them JPG now. And there are 40-60 images there.

With a photo editor I can change the images in uploads folder from BMP to JPG. But the problem is the database. I've seen that in `_postmeta` table images are stored with the **meta_key** `_wp_attached_file` with **meta_value** like `2011/01/canola2.jpg`. And the same image is also in `_posts` table with a detailed path as **guid**, **post_type** `attachment` and **post_mime_type** `image/jpeg`. So may be a similar things happen to the BMP images as well.

So, along with the image file format changes in `uploads` folder how can I bulk edit the db to make them available only with a minor change in their format in database? Any SQL query?

Or, do I have to do the big change manually, one by one?

Comment: For sake of simplicity you could use a search and replace tool to change .jpg to .bmp in the DB. It takes a lot of the hassle out it. The link below is a great resource for doing search and replaces in WP databases. It even gives you a preview of what it's going to change so you can be sure your editing the right things. However, please back up your db otherwise there is no coming back from an erroneous search and replace! http://interconnectit.com/products/search-and-replace-for-wordpress-databases/

Comment: @MichaelJames I considered that, but I found some erroneous blank replacement once in one of my database, that's why I put this in least consideration. Anyways, thanks a lot for the link and a reminder. :)

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you add the files with the matching filenames in the appropriate `wp-content/uploads/` folders you could run a few SQL queries to update the WordPress database to use the `.jpg` files.

Assuming your `wpdb` prefix is `wp` these queries would be:

```
UPDATE wp_posts SET post_mime_type = replace(post_mime_type, 'image/bmp','image/jpeg');

UPDATE wp_posts SET guid = replace(guid, '.bmp','.jpg');

UPDATE wp_postmeta SET meta_value = replace(meta_value, '.bmp','.jpg');
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a plugin that can accomplish that. https://wordpress.org/plugins/better-search-replace/

Just select `wp_posts` and `wp_posts_meta`, check the GUID box, and replace `image/bmp` with `image/jpeg` and `.bmp` with `.jpg`

I changed 5000 images in about 20 seconds.